# Visual Basics read tinyint from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a program that requires there to be an admin type account that after the login page gets a different view, in the user table on MySQL there is a field called Admin which is a tinyint and if it is 1 then the user should access the admin page and if not they should get the standard homepage, how do i validate this?
here is thee code I have already

```
Sub Singnin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Singnin.Click
    Dim sql As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select passwords from Users where Username = '" & Username.Text & "' and passwords = '" & Password.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim isadmin As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select admin from Users where Username = '" & Username.Text & "' and passwords = '" & Password.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim admintrue As Boolean
    conn.Open()
    rs = sql.ExecuteReader
    If rs.Read() Then
        ad = isadmin.ExecuteReader
        If ad.Read() = "1" Then
            Admin_Menu.Show()
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf ad.Read() = "0"
            Homepage.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If


        Password.Text = ""
        Username.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("incorrect username or password")
        Password.Text = ""
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks correct, are you getting an error? I see that you are checking to see if the admin is 1, if it is then show different screen, else 0.

Comment: It is not working, it goes to the admin page regardless whether the user is an admin or not

Comment: you dont need 2 different queries for the same table using the same WHERE; you also very badly need to turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by validate? Your code would satisfy your requirement. A few suggestions, you could combine those 2 sql queries into 1, no need to run 2 separate queries, and you're leaving yourself open to sql injection also. I would suggest using parameters or a stored procedure instead of inline sql queries.

```
Sub Singnin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Singnin.Click

        Dim sql As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select admin from Users where Username = @UserName and passwords = @Password", conn)
        'Dim isadmin As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select admin from Users where Username = '" & Username.Text & "' and passwords = '" & Password.Text & "'", conn)

        Dim admintrue As Boolean

        conn.Open()

        sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName.Text)
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password.Text)

        rs = sql.ExecuteReader

        If rs.Read() Then

            admintrue = RS.item("admin")

            If admintrue = "1" Then
                Admin_Menu.Show()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                Homepage.Show()
                Me.Close()
            End If

            Password.Text = ""
            Username.Text = ""
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            MsgBox("incorrect username or password")
            Password.Text = ""
        End If

        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

Actually, just noticed an error with your original code...

ad.Read() = "1"

This is why it is going to Admin screen always. ad.Read returns a true if a record exists, you would need to put ad.Item("admin")

Comment: I have tried using your code but it just comes up with the incorrect username or password window each time, is this because i copied the code across wrong?                                                                                         I ask this because i am a beginner at programming and am not sure about the standard practise regarding copying code from here

Comment: try adding this line in before the parameters are added... sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text